# Setup with same mount point (help me, please!)

Tags: installation, mount, setup, mountpoint

this is my situation: I want to have installed 4 Operating Systems, by the moment I already have 3 OS installed (Windows XP, Windows XP 64-bit edition and a Linux distro). These are some features of my computer:

- Intel Core i5-2500 processor
- 4 GB of RAM DDR3
- NVIDIA GeForce GT 630 4 GB Graphics Card
- Seagate Barracuda HDD SATA 500 GB
- Seagate Barracuda Green HDD SATA 2 TB
- CD/DVD Multifunction burner
- Multi-Card Reader/Writer

I'd like to install Ubuntu 64-bits (I've seen it, tried it and I have it in a laptop as main OS) but I feel a little unsure about setting the mount point for the install. So, what would happen if I ...?

a.)Set the same mount point (as used with the Linux distro) in different partitions of the same HDD

b.)Set the same mount point in different partitions in different HDDs

Excuse me if I gave little descriptions about the computer and the Linux distro (you may think it would be anyone, included Ubuntu, with no exception). Besides, I apologize if I was rude with the wording of the situation. Any constructive review is welcome.

Note: I've already made the partitions in the HDDs (carefully sized, of course).

Answer (score 0):

Let's suppose this scenario:

- sda1, sda2, sda3 are the 3 partitions where you got installed the listed operating systems;
- sda4 is your free partition

First of all, you can only set a mountpoint for one partition. So if you want to set `/` you can only choose one partition. If you can select two then it should be a bug. There are tools like [LVM](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Lvm) and [mdadm](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SoftwareRAID) that should let you do something similar (use two partitions as the same mountpoint, either mirrored or stripped).

Supposing you want to setup `/` mountpoint. When you select a partition, you have the option to format it. So, if you set the mountpoint of `/` to sda1, if you choose to format it your old OS is gone. If not your system will be installed there, and files with the same name will probably be overwritten.

Hope this helps you.